# Issue with observe livedata in adapter - android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'll give you some hint of my app , maybe help with my issue .

I have an Api an with retrofit I'll get this data . after that insert all data in roomdatabase .

In my main screen with a recyclerview I display all this product (data) .

Near each of this product I have a button to send product to the cart fragment .also have a value(textview) to save each button is pressed to show how many items gone to cart fragment .

I use a upsert(transaction) for insert or update the product to cart fragment .

and after that use a obvserver livedata to display the amount value of products that is send to cart .

First i need A way to implement the observe live data in my main screen instead of adapter / and also is my upsert query is correct ? sometimes when click on products button the other products value changes .

Here is my code :

Dao :

```
    // this is for Maintable

    @Query("SELECT * FROM main")
    fun getalldata(): LiveData<List<Roomtable>>

// cart Table

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Cart")
    fun getAllFromCart(): LiveData<List<CartTable>>


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Cart WHERE id  = :int")
    fun GetAllFromCart(int: Int): LiveData<List<CartTable>>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insertToCart(model: CartTable): Long


    @Query("UPDATE cart SET amount = amount+1 WHERE id = :int")
    fun updateCart(int: Int)


    @Transaction
    fun upsert(model: CartTable) {
        val id = insertToCart(model)

        if (id == -1L) {

            model.id?.let {

                updateCart(it)

            }
```

MainAdapter :

```
class RecyclerAdapterMain(


    private val product: List<Roomtable>,
    val context: Context,
    private val viewlifecyclerOwner: LifecycleOwner

) :

    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMain.ViewHolder>() {


    val viewModel: ViewModelRoom by lazy {

        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(Application()).create(ViewModelRoom::class.java)

    }


    inner class ViewHolder(itemview: View) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {


        val title: TextView = itemview.product_txt

        val price: TextView = itemview.price_product

        val imageproduct: ImageView = itemview.product_image

        val btn_add_product: Button = itemview.btn_add_product

        var amount_value: TextView = itemview.amount_value
    


    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {


        val layoutview =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(layoutview)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = product.size


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


        var products = product[position]

        holder.title.text = products.title
        holder.price.text = products.price
        Picasso.get().load(products.image).into(holder.imageproduct)



        holder.btn_add_product.setOnClickListener {

            products.amount++

            viewModel.upsert(
                CartTable(
                    holder.adapterPosition,
                    products.title,
                    products.price,
                    products.image,
                    products.amount
                )
            )


            viewModel.GetallFromCart(holder.adapterPosition).observe(viewlifecyclerOwner, Observer {

                if (it != null) {

                    for (item in it) {

                        holder.amount_value.text = item.amount.toString()

                    }

                }

            })

        }
```

Main Activity :

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity(){


    val viewModel: ViewModelRoom by lazy {

        ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModelRoom::class.java)


    }



    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.home_activity)


        loadProduct()


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun loadProduct() {

        swipeRefreshMain.isRefreshing = true

        if (hasNetworkAvilable(applicationContext)) {

            viewModel.setup()
            viewModel.products.observe(this, Observer {

                loadrecycler(it)

            })

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "برای بروز رسانی محصولات اینترنت خود را روشن کنید",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            viewModel.getalldata().observe(this, Observer {

                if (!it.isNullOrEmpty()) {

                    loadrecycler(it)


                } else {


                    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setView(R.layout.customalertdialog)
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
                        .create()
                        .show()

                    val constraint = Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build()
                    val workmanager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)
                    val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorkerClass::class.java)
                        .setConstraints(constraint)
                        .build()
                    workmanager.enqueue(workRequest)


                }

            })


        }
    }

    fun loadrecycler(product: List<Roomtable>) {


        val swipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshMain)
        val recycler: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_main)

        recycler.apply {


            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity, 2)

            adapter = RecyclerAdapterMain(
                product, this@HomeActivity, this@HomeActivity )


            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({

                swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false

            }, randomInRange(1, 3) * 1000.toLong())

        }
    }

}
```